# I cant run my python code in idle or pycharm or any platform

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a code to calculate the numerology numbers of the letters, Is my code correct or what is the problem. I use python 3 IDLE only. ERROR =  'local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment'

```
def NNA(name):
    counter
    for i in name:

        if i == 'a' or i == 'i' or i == 'j' or i == 'q' or i == 'y':
            counter = 1

        elif i == 'b' or i == 'k' or i == 'r':
            counter += 2

        elif i == 'c' or i == 'g' or i == 'l' or i == 's':
            counter += 3

        elif i == 'd' or i == 'm' or i == 't':
            counter += 4

        elif i == 'h' or i == 'e' or i == 'n' or i == 'x':
            counter += 5

        elif i == 'u' or i == 'v' or i == 'w': 
            counter += 6

        elif i == 'o' or i == 'z':
            counter += 7


        elif i == 'p' or i == 'f':
            counter += 8

    print(counter)

NNA('guru prasath')
```

Comment: Did your keyboard run out of single quotes? Be more specific than *"cant [sic] run"*, would you? I suspect a `NameError`, which should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I have edited the question take a look now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) you can't increment counter, if you haven't set it to be numeric when initialize: `counter = 0`

2) Your code is very hard to read, you can use more simple and clear way: 
`i in 'aijky'` which is true if i is in your string of letters

```
def NNA(name):
    counter = 0
    for i in name:
        if i in 'aijky':
            counter += 1 
        elif i in 'bkr':
            counter += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't init the variable, python skips empty variables declaration,  try

```
counter = 0
```